# Walk randomly through a binary tree?

Tags: random, tree, scheme, binary-tree

I'm making a program that takes a tree and randomly picks a branch (left or right) and returns those values in a list. For some reason it's not working. Any help?

Example:

```
~(rand-walk (tree 1 (leaf 2) (leaf 3)))
(1 2)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (rand-walk tr)
 (if (empty-tree? tr) '()
   (if (leaf? tr) tr
      (if (equal? (random 1) 0)
              (cons ((root-value tr)(root-value (left-subtree tr))) '())
              (cons ((root-value tr)(root-value (right-subtree tr))) '())))))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add my question. I can't figure out how to return the values in a list. And only the subtrees are returning

Comment: Well, I don't even know **scheme**, but it looks to me like you're not making any recursive calls.  Shouldn't `rand-walk` be called recursively?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't return *anything* if you store numbers in the tree - it has a runtime error because you're applying `(root-value tr)` (as a function) to the `root-value`s of the subtrees.

Comment: Oh, so what should it be instead of root-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a number of problems in your code.  Here is a proper implementation:

```
(define (rand-walk tr)
 (cond ((empty-tree? tr) '())
       ((leaf? tr) (list (root-value tr)))
       ((equal? (random 1) 0)
        (cons (root-value tr) (rand-walk (left-subtree tr))))
       (else
        (cons (root-value tr) (rand-walk (right-subtree tr))))))
```

If I was writing this I would use a tail recursive approach as:

```
(define (rand-walk tr)
  (assert (not (empty-tree? tr)))
  (let walking ((l '()) (tr tr))
    (let ((value (root-value tr)))
      (if (leaf? tr)
          (reverse (cons value l))
          (walking (cons value l))
                   ((if (zero? (random 1)) left-subtree right-subtree) tr))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have never written in Scheme, but I had a brief encounter with LISP about 15 years ago =)

Your recursive part isn't recursive.  You should be calling `rand-walk` on the subtree and `cons`ing that.

```
          (cons ((root-value tr)(rand-walk (left-subtree tr))) '())
          (cons ((root-value tr)(rand-walk (right-subtree tr))) '())))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to traverse it then you should return a list when you reach a leaf:

```
(if (leaf? tr) (cons tr '())
```

And in you recursive steps you should `cons` with some recursive call:

```
(cons (root-value tr) (rand-walk (left-subtree tr)))
```